# Redis sessions и увеличение времени TTFB

Tags: yii2, redis

Есть сайт на YII2. 
До текущего дня все сессии хранились по обычному в файлах. 
Среднее время TTFB составляло 200-500ms.

ОС сервера windows server 2016. 
Apache/2.4.41, PHP/7.1.21

Установили Redis-x64-3.2.100

Подключили сессии через Redis при помощи https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-redis

Среднее время TTFB стало 1500-2000ms.

Отключаем сессии через Redis, TTFB возвращается на значение 200-500ms.

В какую сторону копать? Почему так может происходить с сайтом? Redis из коробки. 
На сервере 4 ядра, 16гб ОЗУ, CPU не забивается даже на 10%. Посещаемость сайта небольшая.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение.

Hostname для подключения указывал как localhost, заменил на 127.0.0.1 и это дало просто космическое ускорение подключения. TTFB вернулся в значение 200ms-500ms и даже меньше.